# How to generate perfect div base pdf in php?

Tags: php, pdf, html

I am generating pdf from html that contains div, Html renders properly in browser but when i write it into pdf it's get damaged.

Currently i am using dompdf library.

Here is my code

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
                    <head>
                    <style type="text/css">
                    div{border:solid 1px;}
                    .mainDiv{float:left;width:500px;}
                    .leftDiv{width:100px;float:left;}
                    .rightDiv{width:100px;float:left;}

                    </style>

                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
                    </head>
                    <body style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <div class="mainDiv">
                        <div class="leftDiv">Name: </div>
                        <div class="rightDiv">Value</div>
                    </div>

                    </body>
                    </html>';   


    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

    $dompdf->load_html($html); 
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));
```

This is how it looks in pdf file
  [image: In Browser]

Comment: .. Show us what you currently have.

Comment: Damaged means it is not rendering in proper format in pdf file.

Comment: So it's what, too big? too small? upside-down? inside-out? Probably worth attaching some screenshots if you can.

Comment: The div with class 'mainDiv' is not covering the two divs inside it although float property is given and for divs having class name 'leftDiv' and 'rightDiv' have not displayed with its actual width 100px.

Comment: Adding <br style="clear:both" /> as the last element of mainDiv should fix the box issue. Not sure about the left and right ones though. Does it work if you use inline styling rather than a class?

Answer (score 1):

You may try **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)**. It has got a lot of functions. It renders HTML perfectly into the page. Also you should use **inline-CSS** instead of `<style type="text/css">` and applying it to elements through classes or IDs.

Here is an example of using CSS style (not as inline) in TCPDF;

**[PHP Code](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps)**, **[PDF Result](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.pdf)**

Comment: still css based property is not applied in this